# Two client queries in that same function

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express

I have a question about if it is right to do two client.queries one right after the other. I am trying to build a REST API. Example:

```
client.query("select waiters_id from waiters", function(err, result){
                     if(err){
                         res.json({success: false, msg: "error"});
                     }
                     if(result.rows.length === 0){
                         done();
                         res.json({success: false, msg: "error"});
                     } else{
                         if(results.rows[0].waiter_id === req.body.waitid){
                                 done();
                                 res.json({success: true, msg: "proceed"});
                             }
                         client.query("insert into waiters",function(err, result){
                              // MORE CODE
                         });
```

I am trying to check if there is a waiter in the waiters table, then insert some specific information into that waiter in that waiters table if there is a waiter. If there is a better way to do this please let me know. I don't want to lose performance. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question really has more to do with SQL then nodejs/express. SQL provides you with the ability to use if statements to make logical assertions about your results:

```
client.query(
  "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM waiters WHERE waiters_id='SomeValue')
      UPDATE waiters SET (...) WHERE waiters_id='SomeValue'
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO waiters VALUES (...)
   SELECT * FROM waiters",
  function (err, result) {
     // do something with results here     
  }
);
```

Which is essentially the same control logic you are trying to build with nodejs. Using the above would eliminate the need for another query.

Comment: Are you using the `node-postgres` module?

Comment: yes, I don't know how I will be writing that in nodejs -postgres

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to implement with `node-postgres` API – remember that all whitespace (including lr/cr) will be stripped by postgres before submitting the query. I would also take a look at the Prepared Statements to clean this up a bit https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Prepared-Statements

Comment: Could you explain to me what the result will give? I am getting an undefined error and I can't seem to figure out how to read it without being undefined.

Comment: The `err` argument of the callback is undefined?

Comment: the result is undefined. If I did just SELECT * from waiters, the result will produce something along these lines: {waiter_id: "1546", waiter_name: "John"}, but with the if exist() you gave me, I don't know how to check if the result is correct.

Comment: Again, easily solved by adding to the SQL. See update.